# Fuelphp How to pass search value from view to controller

Tags: fuelphp

I would like to search and pass a value from view to controller.

Here's my View

```
       <div class="form-group">

            <?php echo Form::label('', 'search', array('class'=>'control-label')); ?>

               <?php echo Form::input('search', Input::post('search',   isset($user) ? $search : ''), array('class' => 'col-md-4 form-control',   'placeholder'=>'search' )); ?>

            <?php echo Html::anchor('admin/users/index/', 'Search', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>

        </div>
```

Here's my Controller

```
public function action_index_search($search = null)
{

    $data ['users'] = DB::select('*')->from('users')->where('username','=', $search)->as_object()->execute();
    $this->template->title = "Users";
    $this->template->content = View::forge('admin/users/index_search', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either check for $_POST in your controller, or better still: break out from `action_search` and use `get_search` and `post_search` controller methods instead :)